# CodeMaid Toolbar drop-down is not appearing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, toolbar, codemaid

#### Environment

- Visual Studio version: Professional 2017 15.4.4
- CodeMaid version: 10.4.53
- Code language: C#

I have CodeMaid installed and enabled but it is not showing on toolbar.

#### Current behavior

I recently had to reinstall Visual Studio 2017 and CodeMaid. Since the reinstall I am no longer seeing the CodeMaid drop-down menu in the toolbar at the top of the Visual Studio window.

#### Expected behavior

The CodeMaid drop-down menu should appear in the toolbar. This will allow me to use the extension as I always have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I had to completely uninstall Visual Studio 2017 and all of its components and do a fresh install. Once I had a fresh copy of Visual Studio 2017 I installed CodeMaid as I normally would and it is now showing in my toolbar without any further configuration.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, there was also the CodeMaid entry missing on right-click in the context menu on my VS 2019.
I verified, that the extension was installed.

I then had to learn, that in my case, the CodeMaid extension had the status "disabled"!?
One indicator is, when you go to Menu - 'Extensions', and below the 'Manage Extensions' entry, there is no CodeMaid option.
You can also verify for sure, by doing the following

1. Go to 'Extensions' - 'Manage Extensions'
2. Select 'Installed' - 'All' and sort alphabetically
3. Scroll down to 'CodeMaid' and click on the icon or the title so that the extension is selected
4. Two buttons should show up, the upper one either says "Disable" or "Enable", depending on the current state of your extension. If it says "Enable", your extension is enabled.

To fix that, just follow these steps:

1. Click on "Enable"
2. Close all Visual Studio windows
3. When you now open VS again, CodeMaid will be active and available again.

Answer (score 1):

Something to try. Right-click on the menu bar, and on the list that appears, select the bottom option, "Customize".

Switch to the "Commands" tab and click the "Add Command..." button. There should be an entry for CodeMaid here that you can select that will add it back to your menu.

[image]

Comment: When following your steps CodeMaid does not appear in the Categories list. I verified again in Extensions and Updates that CodeMaid appears under Installed and that it is enabled. Thank you for the screenshot!

Answer (score 1):

As per [a post on the Visual Studio developer community forum](http://The%20work-around%20is%20to%20delete%20the%20folder%20%25LocalAppData%25%5CMicrosoft%5CVisualStudio%5C15.0_[UniqueID]%5CImageLibrary%20and%20let%20VS%20re-generate%20the%20image%20cache.) you could try deleting the image cache and letting VS rebuild it. Delete the contents of the following folder:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_[UniqueID]\ImageLibrary
```

`%LocalAppData%` for me is `C:\Users\[myUserName]\AppData`

More extreme would be to delete the entire folder:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_[UniqueID]
```

WARNING! This will delete all your Visual Studio settings, customizations and possibly some extensions, and Visual Studio will launch similarly to a fresh install.